# Where did the inquisitors get their lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, comics, star-wars-rebels

In Star Wars rebels and the new Darth Vader comic we see a lot of the Emperors inquisitors and all of them have their own lightsabers (I think they are all double bladed?), but where did they get them? Did they also have to kill a jedi for the crystal and corrupt it or since they are not real sith did the Emperor provide them with a finished lightsaber or even just the crystal?

Answer (score 8):

Currently it is not clear where *all* the inquisitors got their lightsabers, but there are a number of **possibilities**:

**1 - They bled their own lightsabers (they were previously Jedi)**
There were a number of Jedi (especially in [Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Jedi#Galactic_Empire)) that fell to the Dark side and became inquisitors. In becoming inquisitors, they bled their own lightsabers, assuming they still owned them. [The Grand Inquisitor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Inquisitor) is an example of a former Jedi (a Jedi temple guard to be exact) that bled his lightsaber.*

**2 - They killed Jedi to get their lightsabers, then bled them**
This is another likely scenario that has been seen in other comics being performed by Sith as a "conformation" to show that they truely are Sith. This was how Darth Vader acquired his Kyber Crystal for his Red lightsaber, as seen in the [Darth Vader Comic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader:_Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith_3:_The_Chosen_One,_Part_III).

**3 - They were given these lightsabers by the Emperor**
This is the *least likely* explanation, but it could still have occured though I have not been able to find any examples of where Inquisitors were given lightsabers.

*Thanks to Rogue Jedi for pointing this example out.

Comment: We know that the Grand Inquisitor was a former Jedi.

Comment: In the Ahsoka novel, the inquisitor is of an unknown species (to Everyone, including ahsoka), which suggests that he may not have been a Jedi. I'd have to re-read it, but I think it also suggests that he had never actually fought a Jedi yet. This suggests the third option is more likely than you think.

Comment: In the Darth Vader comic they tell you that all the inquisitors were previously Jedi and especially the grand inquisitor who had turned to the dark side because Jedi archivist Jocasto Nu whithheld the secrets in the archives from him. He also fought her later on.